# jQuery replace element

Tags: jquery, json

I have file test.php

```
{"1":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID3","HEALTH1":90.625,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID5","HEALTH2":89.0625},"2":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID3","HEALTH1":81.25,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID5","HEALTH2":78.125},"3":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID3","HEALTH1":71.875,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID5","HEALTH2":67.1875},"4":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID3","HEALTH1":62.5,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID5","HEALTH2":56.25},"5":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID3","HEALTH1":53.125,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID5","HEALTH2":45.3125},"6":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID3","HEALTH1":43.75,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID5","HEALTH2":34.375},"7":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID3","HEALTH1":34.375,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID5","HEALTH2":23.4375},"8":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID3","HEALTH1":25,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID5","HEALTH2":12.5},"9":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID3","HEALTH1":15.625,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID5","HEALTH2":1.5625},"10":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID3","HEALTH1":6.25,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID5","HEALTH2":-9.375},"11":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID3","HEALTH1":-6.875,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID4","HEALTH2":89.0625},"12":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID1","HEALTH1":86.875,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID4","HEALTH2":76.875},"13":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID1","HEALTH1":73.75,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID4","HEALTH2":64.6875},"14":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID1","HEALTH1":60.625,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID4","HEALTH2":52.5},"15":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID1","HEALTH1":47.5,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID4","HEALTH2":40.3125},"16":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID1","HEALTH1":34.375,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID4","HEALTH2":28.125},"17":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID1","HEALTH1":21.25,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID4","HEALTH2":15.9375},"18":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID1","HEALTH1":8.125,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID4","HEALTH2":3.75},"19":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID1","HEALTH1":-5,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID4","HEALTH2":-8.4375},"20":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID2","HEALTH1":85.3125,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID6","HEALTH2":87.5},"21":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID2","HEALTH1":70.625,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID6","HEALTH2":75},"22":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID2","HEALTH1":55.9375,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID6","HEALTH2":62.5},"23":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID2","HEALTH1":41.25,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID6","HEALTH2":50},"24":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID2","HEALTH1":26.5625,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID6","HEALTH2":37.5},"25":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID2","HEALTH1":11.875,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID6","HEALTH2":25},"26":{"PLAYER1":"PLAYER_ID2","HEALTH1":-2.8125,"PLAYER2":"PLAYER_ID6","HEALTH2":12.5}}
```

and  another file:
http://jsfiddle.net/MT3Qf/

It shows me at begin:
current player:PLAYER_ID2
PLAYER_ID3
...

But it's not true that current player is  player_id2. Current player is with id3.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to be treating your data like an array, but it is not.  It is an object with a bunch of properties.  As such, the order in which they might be returned by a function such as `$.each()` is not guaranteed.

You probably need to change your JSON to represent things you want to behave as arrays, as an array.